# Prove or disprove that if $x_n\rightarrow x$ in the metric space $X$ then $(x_n)$ is bounded

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Prove or disprove that if $x_n\rightarrow x$ in the metric space $X$ then $(x_n)$ is bounded.

I was told that the statement is not true hence can be disproved. However, I think the opposite.

if it is convergent then, $d(x_n,l)<ϵ$ for any $ϵ>0$. Therefore, by taking $ϵ=1$, I can define a set such as $M=\{d(x_1,l),d(x_2,l),\ldots,d(x_N1,l),1\}$. If I define an open ball with radius of $\max M$ then wouldn't this ball be the proof that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: You want an open ball of radius slightly larger.

Comment: Well, okay let's say it is slightly larger. Then wouldn't that ball allow us to claim that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: Then why I am told that the statement is false. The T.A. gave the example of $x_n=1/(n-1)$ and said it converges to zero, yet there is no non-trivial open set $O\subseteq X$.

Comment: Are you sure that you got him right? What you say he said is basically incorrect as your argument (mutatis mutandis) shows. If he still claims that he should be able to spot a major flaw in your proof (and not just something that can be fixed).

Comment: Well, the TA is wrong. In the TA's example $x_1$ is not defined. One cannot say that $x_1 = \infty$ because $\infty$ is not a real number. If the sequence starts at $2$, then the sequence is $\{ 1, \frac 12 , \frac 13 , \dots \}$ which is clearly bounded.

Comment: I am sure that I got him correctly since I got 0 points from this question of the assignment even though I provided the above-mentioned reasoning without any notational/logical mistake unlike what you see up there. But, anyway, at least now I know that I was right. Thank you all.

Comment: As pointed out if he still claim that he must surely refute your argument on some ground. I think you should demand that he points out the error in your proof if he want to maintain his standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking correctly, but there are two flaws:

1. You wrote that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $l$, then $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Not quite. Given a $\varepsilon>0$, the inequality $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon$ holds for all but finitely many $n$'s.
2. As you have been told, $\max M$ is not good enough. You should take $1+\max M$, for instance.